# Detecting linear dependence on multiplicative groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let G = $\mathbb{G}_m^2/\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\Gamma \subseteq G(\mathbb{Q})$ be a free abelian group of rank 2. Assume that the set of primes $p$ for which  $\Gamma \mod p$ is cyclic has positive density. Does this imply that $\Gamma$ is contained in a proper algebraic subgroup of G?